# Observers in (Schwarzschild-) de Sitter spacetime

Tags: general-relativity, observers, de-sitter-spacetime

In (pure) de Sitter spacetime, the cosmological horizon is said to be ‘observer dependent’.  I imagine that as the observer always being in the center of that horizon. Another (spacelike separated) observer also has spherical horizon, but a different one.

Consider a test mass in the shared region of both observers. Can both observers reach consensus on anything, such as its position, momentum or energy?

I would know how to answer this if the test particle was in the center of the cosmological horizon, since then the Schwarzschild-de Sitter metric could be used. However, an observer in that metric is also always in the center (right?). Therefore, a more general phrasing of my question is: what does the Schwarzschild-de Sitter metric look like for an observer not at the center?

Comment: There are lots of various subtleties. In GR, even classically, one doesn't have any universal notion of "position". One may use coordinates but there are infinitely many choices and they don't have any invariant meaning. One may calculate proper lengths etc. Classically, the observers will agree about the proper lengths. Quantum mechanically, they should agree as well but the proper length are problematic in quantum gravity as they receive quantum corrections (divergent in the naively quantized GR, and undefined in consistent quantum gravity i.e. string theory).

Comment: The momentum and energy are only sharply well-defined for objects whose wave functions are plane waves, i.e. they breach the boundaries of the cosmic horizon, anyway. So one must always sacrifice some accuracy in these quantities. The thermal noise coming from the cosmic horizon (and its effects) quantifies the minimal amount of uncertainty or disagreement that one has to get by localizing the physics within the de Sitter horizon.